# Tools for format and error checking in your programming language

Tags: discussion, answers, questions, tools

**Lints and Hints:** What tools are available for checking and correcting the conventions, style and common errors in my language (lint tools), and are there tools that can automatically fix them (hint tools)?

This is a follow-up to a comment posted on *[Is there a place for automated code reviews?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5244/23788)*

> Would a list of static analysis tools help jumpstart this? –  [h.j.k.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/27975/h-j-k) [34 mins ago](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5244/is-there-a-place-for-automated-code-reviews#comment11008_5244)

Let's list a few tools that people can use to address easy and common issues in their code before they ask their questions, and that can help reviewers gather "easy" points to mention in their CR answers...:

- [Bash (and other shells)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5271#5271)
- [C, C++](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5255#5255) also [C specific](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5270#5270)
- [C#](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5259#5259)
- [Delphi](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5261#5261)
- [HTML, XHTML, CSS](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5253#5253)
- [Go](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6679/31503)
- [Java](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5256#5256)
- [JavaScript](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5251#5251)
- [jQuery](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5266#5266)
- [JSON](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5262#5262)
- [Lisp](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5269#5269)
- [Lua](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5277#5277)
- [MongoDB](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5273#5273)
- [Objective-C](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5267#5267)
- [Perl](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5268#5268)
- [PHP](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5258#5258)
- [Python](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5252#5252)
- [Regex](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5263#5263)
- [Ruby](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5279#5279)
- [Scala](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5264#5264)
- [SQL](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5257#5257)
- [Swift](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6669/36366)
- [VB.NET](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5254#5254)
- [VB6 and VBA](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5250#5250)
- [XML](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/static-tools-for-most-programming-languages/5265#5265)

---

To keep this organized, please post one tool/language per answer; if it's a paid/commercial tool, please mention it. Also please include a link to the website.

Comment: This should also help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

Comment: Related: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/performance-checking-tools

Comment: Shouldn't the title start with *"Tools for formatting"*? (Not *"Tools for format"*.)

Answer (score 11):

## Python

Python uses Python Enhancement Proposals (PEPs) to improve Python,
ranging from style guides to feature requests.
There are linters for a few of these:

- [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) -- Style Guide for Python Code.

  There are both online ([pep8online.com](http://pep8online.com/)) and offline ([pycodestyle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycodestyle/) <sup>[h](https://github.com/PyCQA/pep8)</sup>) versions for this.
- [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) ([pydocstyle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydocstyle) <sup>[h](https://github.com/GreenSteam/pep257)</sup>) -- Docstring Conventions.
- [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) ([mypy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mypy-lang)<sup>[h](http://mypy-lang.org/)</sup>) -- Type Hints.

There is also "[PEP 7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/) -- Style Guide for C Code".
But this does not seem to have a linter.

---

When starting a new project you might choose to do this:

- "$ [ruff](https://pypi.org/project/ruff) ." -- fast and "not too picky" linter, you should probably do what it suggests.
- "$ [isort](https://pypi.org/project/isort) ." -- "I sort imports so you don't have to", per PEP8, so just do it.
- "$ [black](https://pypi.org/project/black) ." -- will reformat source code, in an opinionated way.

The first two are no-brainers, they won't hurt anything.
Adopting `black` can be a bit more of a hurdle,
but once you bite the bullet there's all manner of
trivial pull-request code review remarks that simply
never arise any more.
Blacked code will typically lint clean.

Start with "$ black -S ." followed by "git diff".
The `-S` says don't turn single- into double- quote strings,
basically noise when you're viewing the initial diffs.
Go through some commits, plus one or two PRs,
and watch the S/N ratio improve.

---

There are also some other analysis tools:

- [pylint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint)<sup>[h](http://www.pylint.org/)</sup>
- [Pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes)<sup>[h](https://github.com/pyflakes/pyflakes)</sup>
- [PyChecker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyChecker)<sup>[h](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/)</sup>

  **Warning**: This imports the code to analyse it.
- [Flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8)<sup>[h](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8)</sup>

  Combines Pyflakes and pycodestyle into one tool.
- [Prospector](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/prospector)<sup>[h](http://prospector.landscape.io/en/master/)</sup>

  Combines all of: pylint, Pyflakes, pycodestyle, pydocstyle and more tools.

---

There are also ways to incorporating some of the above tools into different editors.
For a small list of incorporations:

- [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) has [SublimeLinter 3](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/),
- [vim](http://www.vim.org/) has [pylint.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php%3Fscript_id%3D891) and [pep8](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2914),
- [Atom](https://atom.io/) has [linter-pep8](https://atom.io/packages/linter-pep8),
- [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) has PEP 8 by default,
- [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) has PEP 8 support by default, and
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) that can work with a [long list of linters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_specific-linters), e.g. Pylint and Flake8.

These are good to make sure your answers are PEP 8 compliant,
and so there are no contradictions when saying to follow PEP 8.
However using the tools from the above sections will give a report that you can comment from.

Answer (score 10):

### C / C++

- [Clang's Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), a free static analyzer based on Clang.
- [Coverity](https://www.coverity.com/), a commercial static analyzer, free for open source developers.
- [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/), an open-source static analyzer.
- [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com/), a commercial static analyzer based on Clang.
- [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), free compiler that closely follows C and C++ standards.
- [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org), run-time analyser that is particularly good for the kind of memory errors common in these languages.

---

Simply compiling code with [warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) such as `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` catches quite a number of potential or actual problems.

Answer (score 9):

## VB6 / VBA6 / VBA7 (x86/x64)

- [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) is a free (beer & speech), open-source add in for the VBE IDE  maintained by several members of the [vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) community here on Code Review. For more info see the [rubberduck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubberduck) tag.

Features include static code analysis, code metrics, refactoring tools, Smart Indenter, a unit testing framework, and more.

Direct Link to [Code Inspection Documentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/inspections/list)

Answer (score 9):

## `C#`

- [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) (free)

  It can be run from inside of Visual Studio or integrated into an MSBuild project.
- [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (commercial)

  A paid Visual Studio extension (possibility for open-source "community" license though) with a free 30-day trial.
- [FxCop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (free)

  Can be run standalone, but later versions are bundled into Visual Studio as the "Code Analysis" feature.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript

For JavaScript, there are a few options:

- [JSLint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSLint) (the original, created by Douglas Crockford)
- [JSHint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSHint) (a community-driven fork of JSLint)
- [ESLint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint) (an ES6-compatible fork of JSHint. Necessary if you want to lint ES6 code).

In all cases, if you're using a transpiler like Babel or Traceur, you should run the linter **before** the transpile step. Don't lint compiled code.

Note that all major browsers and other interpreters support the `"use strict";` directive in code, and will ensure that many common mistakes in code are identified before running the code. See: [What does “use strict” do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1335881/1305253)

Answer (score 5):

### HTML5, XHTML, CSS

**Tool:** [Markup validation checker](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options)

Also, there are beautifiers to help improve formatting, [CodeBeautify.org](http://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/) has a good one.

Answer (score 5):

## VB.NET

- [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (commercial)

  A paid Visual Studio extension (possibility for open-source "community" license though) with a free 30-day trial.

Comment: As of the Visual Studio 2015 RC, some of this functionality is built in. https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-vs#ManLang

Comment: @RubberDuck Yeah, VS ended up implementing an actual "rename" refactoring, too. But VS just isn't the same without R# ;)

Answer (score 5):

### Delphi

**Tool:** FixInsight (commercial)

**Website:** https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/fixinsight.asp

Answer (score 4):

## Java

Java lint tools are usually dependent of the IDE you develop in. All the major IDE's (Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans, etc.  - alphabetical order) have mechanisms in place for not only checking for lint-like problems, but also for fixing them too.

Features to expect from your IDE - identification of, and correction of:

1. automatic code formatting (indentation, brace positions, line-wrapping, etc.)
2. redundant code, or impossible code
3. incomplete documentation
4. variable and function name "shadowing"
5. and much, much more.

Standalone tools:

1. [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)
2. [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: There is also a bunch of maven plugins that can be used

Comment: Funny enough running PMD on PMD reveals the exact thing it's trying to correct ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Regex:

### JS-Flavored

- [Debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/) - online regex visual debugger
- [Regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/) - online regex tester
- [Regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) - online tester and debugger

### Offline-Tools:

- [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) - commercial regex-development helper tool, supporting a multitude of regex-flavors and programming languages

Answer (score 4):

### Perl

Plugins:

- [Perl::Lint](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Lint)
- [linter-perl](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-perl)
- [Perl::Critic](http://perlcritic.com/)

Or natively using [`B::Lint`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Lint.html) module.

Answer (score 3):

## SQL

General:

- Program: [Mimer SQL Validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/index.htm)
- Online: [FreeFormatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com/sql-formatter.html)

#### SQL Server / Transact-SQL

Online: [SQL-Format.org](http://www.sql-format.com/)

Natively: [`SET SHOWPLAN_XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187757.aspx)

#### MySQL

Online: [MySQL Syntax Check](http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/)

Natively: [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

#### PostgreSQL & PL/pgSQL

Plugin: [pg-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-validator)

Natively: [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html)

#### SQLite

Plugin: [sqllogictest](http://www.sqlite.org/sqllogictest/doc/trunk/about.wiki)

Natively: [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html)

#### Oracle:

Natively: [`EXPLAIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231)

Answer (score 3):

### PHP

Online:

- [PHP Linter Online](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint-on-line.html)
- [PHPCodeChecker.com](http://phpcodechecker.com/)

Plugins:

- [NuSphere](http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_code_validator.htm)

You can also use the native [`php_check_syntax`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php) from an IDE or command line.

Answer (score 3):

### Objective-C

Plugins:

- [OCLint.org](http://oclint.org/)
- [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/)
- [linter](https://atom.io/packages/linter) *(for Atom.io)*

<sub>These should also work for C/C++</sub>

Comment: Can I be on this list?

Comment: The real question is: Do you _really_ want to? ;-)

Comment: Note `Atom.io` is a text-editor. `linter` is a plug-in for Atom providing the necessary checks for many, many languages.

Comment: Good catch, I corrected it!

Answer (score 3):

## C

- [splint](http://www.splint.org/)

Although not currently actively developed, this free, open-source software provides error checking that can be enhanced with in-code commenting.

Answer (score 3):

#### Bash, Shell

Online:

- [ShellCheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Plugins:

- [bashlint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bashlint)
- [ShellCheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck)

Answer (score 2):

#### JSON

Online validator: [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)

They also have a free [Pro Version](http://pro.jsonlint.com/)

For those at the linux command line, [use `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for all sorts of cool features.

Answer (score 2):

### Scala

Style checker plug-in: [ScalaStyle.org](http://www.scalastyle.org/)

Answer (score 2):

#### XML

Online validators:

- [XML Validation.com](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)
- [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

Plugins:

- [Maven](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/validate-mojo.html)
- [Grails](http://grails.org/plugin/xml-validator)
- [Notepad++](http://www.herongyang.com/XML/NPP-XML-Tools-Plugin.html)
- [FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-US/firefox/addon/xml-developer-toolbar/)

Answer (score 2):

### jQuery

Plugins:

- [jQueryValidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)
- [FormValidator.net](http://formvalidator.net/)

You can also use [JavaScriptLint.com](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php).

Answer (score 2):

#### Lisp

Plugins:

- [LINT: Lint for Common Lisp](http://www-cgi.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/lisp/code/tools/lint/0.html)
- [clavier](http://quickdocs.org/clavier/)

Answer (score 2):

#### MongoDB

Plugins:

- [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) *(for Node.js)*
- [revalidator](https://github.com/flatiron/revalidator) *(for Node.js)*
- [lx-valid](https://github.com/litixsoft/lx-valid) *(for Node.js)*
- [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/) *(for Ruby)*

Or natively use [`validate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/validate/)

Answer (score 2):

#### Lua

Plugins:

- [lua-checker](http://code.google.com/p/lua-checker/)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby

Gems:

- [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) is probably the most popular

But there are [many more](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/code_metrics) each with emphasis on different things (style, code complexity, etc.).

Online:

- Don't know if this counts as it's more like CI, but there's always [CodeClimate](https://codeclimate.com/) (also works for JavaScript, PHP, and Python)

Answer (score 2):

## Swift

- [swiftlint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint)

  - [Metova's fork](https://github.com/metova/SwiftLint)

Answer (score 2):

## Go

- [`golint`](https://github.com/golang/lint) Style and convention problems with documentation, naming, dead-code analysis, and more.
- [`go fmt`](https://blog.golang.org/go-fmt-your-code) adjusts your go code to conform to standard Go style (indentation, spacing, import orders, etc.)
- [`go vet`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet) does deeper static analysis on your code and determines if there are more serious problems in the code, including poorly structured printf statements, etc.

In addition, there are profiling tools, race-condition-analysis tools, and so on that work at program runtime.